# Finding a substring within a list of strings in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'd like to find if there is a substring in any of the strings in my list of strings. I have a list like '("hi" "hey" "hello"). Using "some" I can find if the value "hi" is in this list. But how could I find if just "h" was in at least one of the strings in the list?

Comment: How do you use `some` to check if `"hi"` is in the list?

Comment: something like this, i guess `(some #(clojure.string/includes? % "h") ["hi" "hello" "hey"])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Clojure solutions:**

- [`includes?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/includes_q) from `clojure.string`

```
(some #(clojure.string/includes? % "h") (list "hi" "hello" "hey"))
```

- [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) via Java Interop

```
(some #(.contains % "h") (list "hi" "hello" "hey"))
```

**ClojureScript solutions:**

- [`includes?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/includes_q) from `clojure.string` (require `clojure.string` in `ns` form)

```
(ns my-app.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as string]))

(some #(string/includes? % "h") (list "hi" "hello" "hey"))
```

- [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) via JavaScript Interop

```
(some #(.includes % "h") (list "hi" "hello" "hey"))
```